# How to mock a method call in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I'm writing a test method for Class A, method called m().

m() calls f() on Class B through an instance of B called 'b', but I mock that method call using-

```
def test_m 
@a = A.new
b_mock = MiniTest::Mock.new
b_mock.expect(:f, 'expected_output')
def b_mock.f()
return 'expected output'
end
@a.b = b_mock
end
```

Now A has another method m1(), how can a mock a call to it and get a constant output, using the above or a better approach with Minitest?

Error-

```
NoMethodError: unmocked method :get_group_by_name, expected one of [:]
```

Comment: my advice - run this method of yours with a different data and write down results. Create simple temp expectation tests for that results and refactor the hell out of this behemoth to 10 separate method probably across 2 different classes and then start mocking and unit testing them.... https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers

Comment: good advice, but it has a lot of conditions, if I refactor it, I'll end up with a lot of redundant code.

Comment: at the moment the method is untestable(which is not the word:P) too many things happening in side of it. nested condition etc... it is not a method it is an object with few methods but it is up to you mate;)

Comment: That sounds right, will try and implement -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern OR in Ruby style- https://dockyard.com/blog/2013/07/25/design-patterns-strategy-pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MiniTest Object#stub method, it redefines the method result for the duration of the block.

```
require 'minitest/mock'

class A
  def m1
    m2
    'the original result'
  end

  def m2
    'm2 result'
  end
end

@a = A.new
@a.stub :m1, "the stubbed result" do

  puts @a.m1  # will print 'the stubbed result'
  puts @a.m2

end
```

Read more: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/4.2.0/Object:stub

Comment: thanks, I did just that, but getting an error for a method m2() that m1() is calling- NoMethodError: unmocked method m2()

Comment: I think you have an expectation for `m2` set somewhere, as otherwise it should work, update the question with the code if it doesn't. Or try to compare whatever you have with the code snippet in the answer.

Comment: Ok I posted the actual method and test method. I'm not setting any expectation for m2().

Comment: Great, just use some formatting please, as it's not readable otherwise.

Comment: Well, there is a bit too much irrelevant code, but you current error just says that you should just stub the `get_group_by_name` method on the `@grp_adapter` mock.

Comment: thanks yes, but that was the point of stubbing m1() or create_group_and_add_user(), I did not want to mock stub all methods it was calling. I mean what's the point of stubbing if it's still traversing through that method?

Comment: the original `create_group_and_add_user ` should be never called, so check using the stack trace where the call happened, it couldn't be the mock.

Comment: cool, thanks pal, that was it. there was another method that had to be stubbed. but stub blocks are ugly if you're stubbing multiple methods with several 'do..end' for each method stubbed. thanks again for your time.